# XmlWriter disable convert value

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

I have got a problem with XmlWriter during save for example: 0.000036 value. During serialize it's convert to 3.6E-05 value. I don't know why!

If someone knows how solve this problem I will be greatful.
Below it's sample of my code:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();

using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter()) {
    xs.Serialize(writer,o);   
}

XElement xElement = doc.Root;

return xElement;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `XmlWriter` converts strongly typed data to string.

If you try

```
var val = 0.000036;
var stringval = val.ToString();
```

you will get

```
"3.6E-05"
```

if you try then

```
var doubleVal = Convert.ToDouble(stringval);
```

you will get

`0.000036` again.

So basically, it's just the string representation of the value.

By the way, you can also declare a double as

```
var myDouble = 3.6E-05;
```

Comment: from msdn:
_The XmlWriter converts the value to its string representations according to the XML Schema (XSD) data type rules_
[XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#double)

Comment: It's answers which I expect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: But I have got another question relate to earlier. I describe situation.

I serialize value from text box for example 0.000036. Into Xml object it's save as 3,6E-05. Next I want to retrieve this value (3,6E-05) and assign to text box to Text property (string). But I want to locate inside text box value 0.000036 not 3,6E-05. 

How can I do it?

Comment: @Jaro Well, you could do something like `val.ToString(".###########")`. Number of `#` = max digits shown after the `.`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with that those values are equal (as double can be equal). This is just syntax for `3.6 * 10^-5`.